# Make Chrome tell the user that it is downloading

Tags: chrome-for-android

When I click a link to download a file ([example](https://t.co/MGBem5xz8g?amp=1)), the file gets downloaded without any toast, popup or any indication (except in notification panel) . If I refresh the page again, it asks me if I want to download again as in screen shot below

[image]

Chrome :`89.0.4389.90` (latest on Play Store, but same behavior noticed on earlier versions too)

Device : Pixel 4a, Android 11, November update (also saw the same behavior on One Plus 7, Android 10)

**How can I make Chrome tell me that it's downloading the first time?** (including rooted means as a last resort).

I can check the notification panel or downloads but that is an unnecessary step. Similarly, I don't want to create an automated pop up.

I checked settings and flags (`Chrome://flags`) but couldn't find any way to change this  behavior

Comment: This happens because you have set "Ask where to save files" to Off. If you set it to On, the dialog box to "Choose where to download" will be shown. That will be the indication that it is about to download the file (not downloading unfortunately).

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio Thanks, I noticed this but as you rightly pointed out , looking for "downloading" indication